# Should there be a brush tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I noticed [this question](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/260/what-kind-of-brush-to-use-with-a-cavalier-king-charles-spaniel) that has a [brush](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brush) tag. Do we need a [brush](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brush) tag?

I think since there is already a [grooming](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grooming) tag, there is no need for [brush](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brush) tag.

What does the community think about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grooming seems to be a good enough tag, the other one seems superfluous and should likely be removed.

Comment: There was only one question.  I removed the [tag:brush] tag from it (it was already tagged [tag:grooming]).

Comment: @mon there is more than one question about brushing, just not tagged

Comment: Ok, so if we want a "brushing" tag then more work is needed to find those questions anyway.  It feels too specialized to me; "grooming" seems fine for this.  I mean, we also don't have tags for "shampooing" and "flossing" and "nail-trimming" (I hope :-) ).